# Azure Data Explorer / Kusto JSON Ingestion Transform (GetPathElement)

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-explorer

I have some troubles understanding the ingestion of JSON entries (from Event Hubs) into Kusto / ADX. I seem not to be able to get the GetPathElement transform statement to work. I'd expected that something like

[{"test":"name","path":"$.content.something","transform":"GetPathElement(0)"}]

would work (according to documentation). Unfortunately, I get the (imo) undocumented error:

Value 'GetPathElement(0)' used in a switch/case is invalid

Can someone give me a hint/example on how GetPathElement should work?

Comment: A sample of the json would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This transformation option indeed doesn't work.
I am not sure this transformation meant to do what you are expecting from it.
If it had worked correction, it would put the constant word 'something' to each ingested row.
Is this what you meant to get? If yes, you can use 'ConstValue' property of the mapping.
If you mean anything different, please, explain in more details.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I wanted to have the constant word "something". The ConstValue property was/is not documented for JSON...

Comment: This is what the docs say about 'path' property: If starts with $: JSON path to the field that will become the content of the column in the JSON document (JSON path that denotes the entire document is $). If the value does not start with $: a constant value is used.        So, you should use 'path' to set the constant value.

Answer (score 0):

can you share your ingest statement.

also you can do a 1-click ingestion which, do not complete the setup but just point it to the JSON file and it will give you an ingest commands to run with Table schema commands and etc which you can then run in kusto explorer or through Azure Portal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-one-click